# community builder is showing all the pages based on Customer Service template blank suddenly

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, lightning-community, community-builder

Community builder is showing all the pages based on Customer Service template blank suddenly. Browser console showing security error.
It is standard Salesforce tool giving error for standard functionality.
Please note - pages based on custom layout are opening correctly.
Has anyone faced this issue earlier? Any suggestion? Any Hint?
Any input will be really helpful and very much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with Salesforce Communities.

[image]

This should have been solved now.